# PHP stream_select doesnt work

Tags: php, windows, proc-open

I'm using Windows 7 and php 5.

I have a problem with executing a process by proc_open and check the timeout.
I used stream_select to check the timeout with this code:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
0 => array("file", $infile, "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$prog = @proc_open ($objname.".exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes, "$DOCUMENT_ROOT/judge/temp", null, null);
if(!is_resource($prog)) ErrorResult("","proc_open err");

$streams = array($pipes[1]);
$start = microtime(true);
$ret = stream_select($streams, $a = null,$a = null, 1);
$stop = microtime(true);
?>
```

This is the C++ code I used to test that:

```
#include<windows.h>

int main(){
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

In that code, there's no output at all, but stream_select doesn't wait 1 sec and return 1.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What do `$ret` and `$streams` contain after `stream_select` returns? Please provide a `var_dump`. If `$ret` > 0 then then `$streams` should not be empty. If `$streams` is not empty, what do you get when you read from the streams contained within it?

Comment: Also are you sure `$pipes[1]` is correct? You are specifying only 2 pipes, maybe `$pipes[0]` is what you need.

Comment: $ret == 1 and $streams is not empty. I can read nothing.

Comment: I'm sure that $pipes[1] is correct, I confirmed that is right.

Comment: Use `stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0)`.  Although how that would affect already the select is beyond me.

Comment: it returns FALSE, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your C++ executable might not be really executed for some reason, but that the exit code could be hidden from you by `cmd.exe`.

- Get a proof that the C++ executable actually runs at all.  Attempt to pass some data from C++ to PHP already before calling `stream_select`.
- Get `cmd.exe` out of your way:

  $opts = array('suppress_errors' => false, 'bypass_shell' => true);

  $prog = proc_open ($objname.".exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes, "$DOCUMENT_ROOT/judge/temp", null, null, $opts);

Comment: @박수찬 - Rewrote answer based on everything ruled out so far.